# *strings.Reader leaving target buffer blank

Tags: go, semantics

I am attempting to pass an `*strings.Reader` from one function to another. The content of the reader is `"Foo"`. This is the code that creates/passes the reader:

```golang
_, err = funcNum2(strings.NewReader("Foo"))
```

... and the code that reads from it...

```golang
buf := []byte{}
_, err := reader.Read(buf)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error reading from reader: %v\n", err)
}
```

When I run the debugger and look at the value of `reader` in `method2`, I find that `reader` still contains `"Foo"`. However, can you please help me understand why, when I try to read into `buf`, `buf` is empty?

Comment: Raed does not consume any bytes because the size of `buf` is zero.  See https://go.dev/play/p/TXFj1Ns4tTX.

Comment: Reading the [`io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) documentation will illuminate what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when assigning `buf:=[]byte{}`, a byte slice of size 0 is assigned. In order to read from buffer you can take size of the reader's buffer, `reader.Size()`, create a byte slice of that size. Write to it.

following code works

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func print_reader(read *strings.Reader) {
    buf := make([]byte, 4) //give read.Size() here
    n, err := read.Read(buf)
    fmt.Println(n, err, string(buf), read.Size())
}

func main() {
    rd := strings.NewReader("test")
    print_reader(rd)
}
```